# VS Code run command looking weird

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am currently learning C and installed GCC and the VS Code extensions "C/C++", "C/C++ Extensions" and "Runner". Everything is working, but I was told that I should run programs that require an input from the user in "Terminal" instead of "Output" (there's a simple setting for that).
**This is my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Input:\n");
    int input;
    scanf("%d", &input);
    printf("You typed: %d", input);

    return 0;
}
```

**This is how it looks:**
[VS Code Terminal command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpq1v.png)
So how can I fix this spacing bug? (The run command is auto-generated (probably by runner), in the normal Output everything was working fine)

I've already searched in the settings, but couldn't find anything...

NOTE: I have already closed and reopened VS Code